# backtracking line search in R

Tags: algorithm, r, backtracking

why backtracking(step halving) line serach get fail? actually sometimes in my R code i have an ascent direction and step size $t = 1e-21$  which means that  Error: Line search failed (tol=1e-10) and i chose alpha=0.3 and beta=0.5.

Comment: If you want a better answer than 'because your code is broken' I think you need to show us a little more of it.

Comment: Show us your code, already! A complete reproducible snippet please! Doublecheck it is reproducible before you post!

Comment: I'm kind of curious about the upvotes here. I can appreciate not *downvoting* (to give the OP a chance to edit and add more information), but "this question shows research effort: it is useful and clear" doesn't seem to be true ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a wild guess and say that thanks to floating point round off, you can't reliably make steps that small.

But really I don't know.  Nor will anyone else until you follow the suggestion to actually show us what is not working.